# How to split date of a list?

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list:

```
['Sun Oct 24 10:31:10 +0000 2021','Sun Oct 24 10:45:02 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:13:27 +0000 2021',
 'Mon Oct 25 04:26:20 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:32:32 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:56:39 +0000 2021',
 'Mon Oct 25 05:21:21 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 06:46:27 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 08:59:13 +0000 2021']
```

How can I get this result:

```
['Sun Oct 24', 'Sun Oct 24', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25',
 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed format dates, you can just take first 10 chars of every string date

```
dates = ['Sun Oct 24 10:31:10 +0000 2021','Sun Oct 24 10:45:02 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:13:27 +0000 2021',
 'Mon Oct 25 04:26:20 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:32:32 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:56:39 +0000 2021',
 'Mon Oct 25 05:21:21 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 06:46:27 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 08:59:13 +0000 2021']


trunc_dates = [
    date[:10] for date in dates
]

print(trunc_dates)
```

Output

```
['Sun Oct 24', 'Sun Oct 24', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25']
```

Also you can use more reliable solution with parsing via [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/) and formatting

```
from dateutil import parser

dates = ['Sun Oct 24 10:31:10 +0000 2021','Sun Oct 24 10:45:02 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:13:27 +0000 2021',
 'Mon Oct 25 04:26:20 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:32:32 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 04:56:39 +0000 2021',
 'Mon Oct 25 05:21:21 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 06:46:27 +0000 2021','Mon Oct 25 08:59:13 +0000 2021']



trunc_dates = [
    parser.parse(date).strftime('%a %b %d')
    for date in dates
]

print(trunc_dates)
```

Output

```
['Sun Oct 24', 'Sun Oct 24', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25']
```

Comment: Or maybe more universally, use some date/time formatting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Answer (score 0):

We could use `re.sub` here for a regex based approach:

```py
inp = ['Sun Oct 24 10:31:10 +0000 2021', 'Sun Oct 24 10:45:02 +0000 2021', 'Mon Oct 25 04:13:27 +0000 2021', 'Mon Oct 25 04:26:20 +0000 2021', 'Mon Oct 25 04:32:32 +0000 2021', 'Mon Oct 25 04:56:39 +0000 2021', 'Mon Oct 25 05:21:21 +0000 2021', 'Mon Oct 25 06:46:27 +0000 2021', 'Mon Oct 25 08:59:13 +0000 2021']
output = [re.sub(r'\s+\d{2}:.*$', '', x) for x in inp]
print(output)

# ['Sun Oct 24', 'Sun Oct 24', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25',
   'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25', 'Mon Oct 25']
```